# About Oracle Coherence (and WLS)

Tags: weblogic

The Coherence functionality seems to based on clustering concept. Does this mean that, if I want to install WLS on my system for development use, I do not need the Coherence component that comes with WLS ?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it is not required to use WLS.

Answer (score 1):

This may help to answer the question:

- Coherence is now on the same "release train" as WebLogic, starting with version WebLogic version 12.1.2 (which is the second point release of the WebLogic "12c" major release version). So from now on, Coherence and WebLogic versions are in sync, and the two products are tested and certified together.
- Coherence is "physically" included as part of some WebLogic installers. Coherence can be purchased as a separate product (three editions: Standard, Enterprise, Grid), or it can be purchased as part of the WebLogic Suite product (which comes with Enterprise Edition, but can be upgraded to Grid Edition).
- WebLogic now has a free developer license available, and that free developer license covers Coherence development as well. (Previously, customers had to pay for a developer license, mainly AFAICT because that is how the database was licensed. We are glad to have fixed this!)
- WebLogic can be used without Coherence. Coherence can be used without WebLogic. And both products can also be used together, using Coherence*Web for session management, WebLogic Active Cache for simple caching use cases, or Coherence Containers for full-blown, deployable, life-cycle managed, multi-tier data grid applications that are integrated with Java EE applications on WebLogic.

I hope this helps to clarify the possible options that you have.

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*